# Parsing structured data in a functional way (e.g. without mutating)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing, functional-programming, immutability

Imagine you have the following data in a file:

```
Group1
  Thing1
  Thing2
Group2
  Thing1
  Thing2
  Thing3
Group3
Group4
  Thing1
```

It's easy to write a "parser" which loops through the file line-by-line, remembering the current `Group` (in a variable) and then writing all the `Thing`s to an object, neatly grouped by their respective group:

```
// Very naive implementation for illustrative purposes only
let groups = {}
let currentGroup = null
data
  .split(/\n/)
  .forEach(entry => {
    const matches = entry.match(/^(Group\d+)$/)
    if (matches) {
      currentGroup = matches[1]
      groups[currentGroup] = []
    } else {
      groups[currentGroup].push(entry.trim())
    }
  })
```

which gives me:

```
{
  Group1: [
    'Thing1', 'Thing2'
  ],
  Group2: [
    'Thing1', 'Thing2', 'Thing3'
  ],
  ...
}
```

What's the best way to achieve this without mutating `groups` and `currentGroup`, in a purely functional way? Do I need to take a harder look at `Array.reduce`, because I've seen some (IMHO rather mind-boggling) use-cases to transform an Array into an Object, or is that not going to help here?

Comment: what means without *mutating*? you need somewhere the group to group to group the following parts.

Comment: I was talking about not mutating **existing** values, but rather creating altered copies, which is typical for the functional programming paradigm. For instance, instead of `let person = { name: 'Nina' }; person.lastName = 'Scholz'`, I'd prefer `const person = { name: 'Nina' }; const personNew = Object.assign({}, person, { lastName: 'Scholz' })`

Comment: You can easily achieve this with recursion. Current engines are not optimized for recursion though (no TCO). So you better stick with the suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd want to use `reduce` here:

```
data
.split(/\n/)
.reduce(({groups, currentGroup}, entry) => {
  const matches = entry.match(/^(Group\d+)$/)
  if (matches) {
    groups[matches[1]] = []
    return {currentGroup: matches[1], groups};
  } else {
    groups[currentGroup] = groups[currentGroup].concat([entry.trim()]);
    return {currentGroup, groups};
  }
}, {groups: {}, currentGroup: null})
.groups
```

However, there is no reasonable way in JS to create a map object without mutation. As long as you keep your property assignments local, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering whether there's a better alternative to local assignments.